# Rendering an Image with a Specific Size

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I want to render an image that is, for example, 170 px by 180 px. How can this be done in blender? I'm using the cycles render. Is the process any different for an animation?

Comment: Yeah, it's probably a duplicate, but I like this question and answer better. It's actually more useful, I think.

Comment: I was asking a slightly different question. That is how to increase the resolution. Of course, because I'm a noob, they have the same answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can specify the render size in the dimensions section on the render panel just as you do for any other image rendering. To get the full resolution of the final image, also make sure that the *Percentage scale for render resolution* slider is set to `100%`.

This setting is also for animations, and behaves exactly the same way.

[image]

In **Blender 2.8 and above** the setting is in the Properties Panel under *Output Properties > Dimensions > Resolution X,Y*

[image: Blender 2.8 render dimensions setting]